# Call to a member function saveAs() on string in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

When i am trying to upload imgage file to `projectfolder\uploaded` directory i got error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function saveAs() on string

My controller code is as below

```
public function actionStore()
{       
    $model = new Article;

    $this->performArticleValidation($model);

    $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();                

    if(isset($_POST['Article'])) {          
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Article'];
        $model->avatar = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');
        //var_dump($model->avatar); // Outside if
        if($model->save()) {
            //var_dump($model->avatar); // Inside if
            $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../uploaded';      
            $model->avatar->saveAs($path);
            EUserFlash::setSuccessMessage('Thank you.');
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Model is as below

```
public function rules() {        
    return array(
        array(['avatar'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'types' => 'jpg, jpeg, gif, png'),
    );

}
```

When I tried to debug `$model->avatar` outside if condition it gives me an array of an object as shown in below image and inside if it gives me the string.

form attribute for image upload is avatar
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to pass file name in `saveAs()` i am just passing directory path only so image not uploaded.

```
public function actionStore()
{
    $model = new Article;

    $this->performArticleValidation($model);

    $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();                

    if(isset($_POST['Article'])) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Article'];
        $model->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());

        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'avatar');
        $model->avatar = strtotime("now").'.'.$uploadedFile->getExtensionName();
        $model->created_by = $userId;

        if($model->save()) {    

            $path = Yii::app()->basePath.'\..\uploaded\articles';
            $uploadedFile->saveAs($path.'/'.$model->avatar);

            EUserFlash::setSuccessMessage('Thank you.');
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$model->avatar->saveAs($path);`

here you are trying to call `saveAs()` on avatar

but somehow instead of an object avatar is a string. maybe avatar was always a string.

```
var_dump($model->avatar)
```

would produce a string.

that is what the error message shows

Comment: `$model->avatar` is not always string if I `var_dump($model->avatar)` before if i get array of object but after save() i get string

Comment: now you have the exact problem(the actual bug). you can try figuring it out.